# Is the function continuous, being made up of 2 discontinuous functions?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity

Is the following function continuous, eventhough l(x) and h(x) are discontinuous? I thought it would be as at x=2 their would still be a y-value = 2.

$$l,h: (\mathbb{R},   \mathbb{R}) $$
$$l(x) = 2, x≥2$$
$$h(x) = -2, x <2$$

Comment: This doesn't make sense. What do you mean by $(f, g) : (\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R})$, and what does it have to do with $l$ and $h$?

Comment: sorry that was my mistake. It's supposed to be $l, h$

Comment: It still doesn't make sense. What do you mean by $l, h : (\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R})$? The functions $l$ and $h$ *are* continuous on their domains.

Comment: yes, the sum of two discontinuous functions can be continuous. By example if $f$ is a discontinuous function and $g:=c-f$ for some $c\in\Bbb R$ then $f+g=c$, what is continuous. But in your question both functions $l$ and $h$ are continuous.

Comment: If you're looking for sum of two discontinuous functions which is continuous consider $f(x)=1$ if x is rational and $f(x)=0$ if x is irrational and $g(x)=0$ if x is rational and $g(x)=1$ if x is irrational then $f(x)+g(x)=1$ for all $x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No,
because
$\lim_{x \to 2^-} f(x)
\ne f(2)
$.